# How to do Minimize redirects in gtmetrix 0 to 100% for increasing site speed in htaccess code

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, pagespeed, google-pagespeed, gtmetrix

My Website is running on HTTP so client wants to make the site with HTTPS along with WWW then the site will redirect two times but it will decrease the site speed loading time because it will load the site in two times,and for redirect i am using for HTTP to HTTPS and non WWW to WWW ht-aces  please help me for in geometric i will make 100% Remove the redirect chain if possible

Answer (score 0):

You can't. If user fill in the wrong (non-canonical - non-www, non-https) site address, then it will be forced to be redirected. And this is OK. Understand? There are just a couple of cases ypur user can do:

- Fill in http://example.com - Results: 2 redirects, first - to https, second - to www
- Fill in https://example.com - Results: one redirect - to www
- Fill in http://www.example.com - Results: one redirects - to https
- Fill in https://www.example.com - Results: no redirects, canonical address was filled in.

The single thing what you can do to minimize the amount of redirects, is to earn backlinks, which link your canonical (**https://www**.example.com) address.